# Optimal way to "mirror" JSON data from a third-party to a Meteor Collection

Tags: json, algorithm, mongodb, meteor, mirroring

We have a Meteor-based system that basically polls for data from a third-party REST API, loops through the retrieved data, inserts or updates each record to a Meteor collection.

But then it hit me: What happens when an entry is deleted from the data of the third-party?

- One would say insert/update the data, and then loop through the collection and find out which one isn't in the fetched data. True, that's one way of doing it.
- Another would be to clear the collection, and rewrite everything from the fetched data.

But with thousands of entries (currently at 1500+ records, will potentially explode), both seem to be very slow and CPU consuming.

*What is the most optimal procedure to mirror data from JS Object to a Meteor/Mongo collection in such a way that deleted items from the data are also deleted on the collection?*.

<sub>I think code is irrelevant here since this could be applicable to other languages that can do a similar feat.</sub>

Comment: Could give us some background like data size, consistency requirements, access patterns? Right now it seems you could do better with some kind of in-memory database instead off MongoDB.

Comment: When you say "loop through the collection" do you mean query?  Or is that a 3rd option you have eliminated?

Comment: What's the goal you want to achieve here? I think that if you want to use the third-party data as Meteor collection, you'd better keep it in memory and fake the collection behavior. By the way, Meteor polls Mongo in about 5 seconds intervals, so 1 second is a bit of overkill here.

Comment: @HubertOG We are trying to "clone" data from a third-party into a collection in Meteor so everyone fetches it from the collection instead of the third-party. So basically we are already doing that.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of usage try using something that's more optimized. The meteor guys are working on using meteor as a sort of replica mongodb set to get/and set data.

For the moment there is Smart-Collections that uses mongodb's oplog to significantly boost performance. It could work in a sort of one size fits all scenario without optimizing for specifics. There are [benchmarks](http://meteorhacks.com/making-meteor-500-faster-with-smart-collections.html) that show this.

When Meteor 1.0 comes out I think they'll have optimized their own mongodb driver.

I think this may help with thousands of entries. If you're changing thousands of documents every second you need to get something closer to mongodb. Meteor employs lots of caching techniques which aren't too optimal for this. I think it polls the database every 5 seconds to refresh its cache.

Smart Collections: http://meteorhacks.com/introducing-smart-collections.html

Please do let know if it helps I'm interested to know if its useful in this scenario.

If this doesn't work, redis might be helpful too since everything is stored in-memory. Not sure what your use case is but if you don't need persistence redis would squeeze out more performance than mongo.